# How to use the onCameraFrame function efficiently by not processing every single frame to increase the fps

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision

I am working on an Augmented Reality Android application. I am getting the fps of approx 20 frames when no processing is being done and the fps of approx 3 frames when I run my ARFilter (Device: ASUS TRANSFORMER PAD TF700T). I am using ORB, FREAK and BRUTEFORCE HAMMING for detection, description and matching respectively. I have tried to set the resolution by setMaxFrameSize(640, 480); but I could manage only an increase of 1fps. Should I use a counter and what actually happens when a counter runs through the "onCameraFrame" function.

```
@Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(final CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        final Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();

        if (ARFil != null) {
            // if (counter % 10 == 0) {
            ARFil[ARFilInd].apply(rgba, rgba);
            // }

            // addCounter();
        }

        return rgba;
    }


// Added method addCounter()
    /*
     * private void addCounter() { if (counter > 20) { counter = 0;
     * 
     * } counter++;
     * 
     * }
     */
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I have found an interesting answer for the question I have posted above from the earlier post "Parallel image detection and camera preview OpenCV Android"

Comment: Waqas I would be interested to see what results you get from using post 15799487 . I wish there was some example code.

Comment: Sure Ryan. I will share with you if I get any positive result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's late, but if it can help I have some hypothesis:

- you might need to decrease your image size even further;
- you might need to limit the number of features you match to a lower threshold;
- you might need to convert some code to NEON to run in real-time, or to GPU;
- you might need to change the algorithms you are using, decreasing cyclomatic complexity;
- FREAK is not fast enough for real-time mobile, so I would go with something like DAISY;
- don't know if you activated compiler optimizations when you built the app, but they are definitely needed (if you use C++ at least).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. very informative. I managed to increase the frame rates last year by following some of the steps you mentioned above. However, let me mark this as the answer.